# Micrometer gauge not appearing on prometheus endpoint

Tags: gauge, micrometer

I have instrumented my code inside a method for micrometer gauge like this:

```
SimpleMeterRegistry registry = new SimpleMeterRegistry();
Gauge
     .builder("greeting_service_gauge", new AtomicInteger(new Random().nextInt(10)), AtomicInteger::get)
     .register(registry);
```

I have added few other metrics too.

Other metrics appear on prometheus endpoint, but this gauge metrics doesn't.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3):

You are registering the gauge to the `SimpleMeterRegistry`. Instead you should be registering the metric to the Prometheus registry (or the CompositeMeterRegistry)

You can inject the `MeterRegistry` if this is a Spring project. Or use the global `Metrics.globalRegistry` to get the composite one.

```
Gauge
     .builder("greeting_service_gauge", new AtomicInteger(new Random().nextInt(10)), AtomicInteger::get)
     .register(Metrics.globalRegistry);
```

Comment: having similar issue with AWS - gauge is not visible on aws CloudWatch

Comment: Are you commenting to say my answer helped you? If not, I recommend creating a new question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68984348/confusion-about-micrometer-metrics-isnt-the-gauge-supposed-to-calculate-the-v I've few basic doubts, will be great if you can check @checketts